# jHipster: Search criteria "GreaterThan,LessThan" for date time

Tags: java, angular, typescript, jhipster

In my jHipster project I want to search row by datetime range.
The fragments of my code are:

***product-inquiry-view.component.html***

```
<div class="input-group date" id='datetimepicker'>
    <input id="field_dateStart" #dateStart="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="criteriaByStartDate"/>
    <input id="field_dateEnd"  #dateEnd="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="criteriaByEndDate"/>
    <button (click)="findByCriteria()"
    </button>
</div>
```

Component class:

***product-inquiry-view.component.ts***

```
export class ProductInquiryViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

criteriaByStartDate: string;
criteriaByEndDate: string;
..........
findByCriteria() {

    criteriaByStartDate: Date;
    criteriaByEndDate: Date;

    let criteriaByStartDate = this.criteriaByStartDate;
    let criteriaByEndDate = this.criteriaByEndDate

    this.productInquiryViewService
        .query({
            'piDate.greaterThan': criteriaByStartDate,
            'piDate.lessThan': criteriaByEndDate,
            'piDocnum.contains': this.criteriaByDocnum
        }).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<IProductInquiryView[]>) => {
            this.productInquiryViews = res.body;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
}
```

Controller:

***ProductInquiryViewResource.java***

```
@GetMapping("/product-inquiry-views")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<ProductInquiryViewDTO>> getAllProductInquiryViews(ProductInquiryViewCriteria criteria) {
    log.debug("REST request to get ProductInquiryViews by criteria: {}", criteria);
    List<ProductInquiryViewDTO> entityList = productInquiryViewQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(entityList);
}
```

And I got exception:

```
 2019-04-15 12:48:45.910  WARN 24330 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException:
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'productInquiryViewCriteria' on field 'piDate.greaterThan': rejected value [Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0300]; codes 
[typeMismatch.productInquiryViewCriteria.piDate.greaterThan,typeMismatch.piDate.greaterThan,typeMismatch.greaterThan,typeMismatch.java.time.ZonedDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productInquiryViewCriteria.piDate.greaterThan,piDate.greaterThan]; arguments [];
default message [piDate.greaterThan]]; default message [Failed to convert  property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime' 
for property 'piDate.greaterThan'; nested exception is  org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] 
to type [java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value 'Mon Apr 01 2019  00:00:00 GMT 0300'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0300]]   enter code here
```

I see that "Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0300" is not correst string for parsing to ZoneDateTime, so I tried send criteria in such format :

```
"2019-04-01T00:15:30+03:00[Europe/Moscow]";
```

Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be :

```
this.productInquiryViewService
        .query({
            'piDate.greaterThan': criteriaByStartDate.toISOString(),
            'piDate.lessThan': criteriaByEndDate.toISOString(),
...
```